# How to Implement Multi-hand Gesture Recognition with Mediapipe Model Maker

Tags: android, machine-learning, deep-learning, gesture-recognition, mediapipe

I am working on Hand Gesture Classification. I came across Google's Hand Gesture Recognizer which uses Mediapipe Model Maker (e.g: "from mediapipe_model_maker import gesture_recognizer") to train the model and generates .task file which I use on Android for prediction.
My Question is that the model is only able to recognize my one hand. However, I have signs which require both hands. How can I customize the model in such a way that the model trains and give me predictions in Android on both hands?

https://mediapipe-studio.webapps.google.com/demo/gesture_recognizer
https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/gesture_recognizer

In Android Code, I did:
private var defaultNumResults = 2 //was 1 before
I expected that it will detect both hands, but it was still detecting one hand.
Code link: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/gesture_recognizer/android

In python code used to train and make the .task file, I was not able to find any way to customize the model in such a way that it recognizes both hands.
Code link: https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/gesture_recognizer/python

Answer (score 0):

> In python code used to train and make the .task file

As you can see you call method gesture_recognizer.Dataset.from_folder which also call method _get_hand_data [_get_hand_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUs7D.png)
Number of hands equal to 1 for dataset loader process. You can try to override Dataset load logic or write it by your own.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).